# ASP MVC Validation Password and confirm password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I must Validation Password and confirm password. I used `Compare`, but when password and confirm password there are null, display ErrorMessage.

What to do, it should not display ErrorMessage, when Password and confirm password both are blank.

Comment: Use the Required attribute

Answer (score 10):

I recommend the FluentValidation library where you can specify such complex scenarios declaratively.

```
RuleFor(customer => customer.Password)
.Equal(customer => customer.PasswordConfirmation)
.When(customer=>!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(customer.Password));
```

You can install the library using NuGet

```
PM> Install-Package FluentValidation.MVC4
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.MVC4/

Comment: @AKhudairy does not soudn to me like one. In my opinion, attributes are much better and much versatile.

Comment: it's nice to have options. I use attributes too, but you don't know what you might need.

Comment: @AgentFire, having the validators with FluentValidation allows you to reuse the same validation for different UI, web, desktop... the only thing you need to do is call the Validate method passing the object, and also you can perform some logic, like going to the database and ask for existing users, the approach is very simple and you don't need to create your own attribute, everything is on the same file, IMHO I vote for FluentValidation

Comment: this solution works in `.net core` as well. `PM> Install-Package FluentValidation.AspNetCore`

Answer (score 4):

Use `[Compare]` for the equality match and `[Required]` to avoid blank values.

Comment: Password is optional, and not is Required. The problem is, when password is null and confirm passowrd id null, then display ErrorMassage: "Password and ConfirmPassword are not the same"

Comment: You could implement your own custom validator.

Answer (score 4):

Using FluentValidation, I prefer to split the validator into different rules.

First can be only

```
 RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please enter the password");
 RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please enter the confirmation password");
```

And second the comparison between both:

```
 RuleFor(x => x).Custom((x, context) =>
        {
            if (x.Password != x.ConfirmPassword)
            {
                context.AddFailure(nameof(x.Password), "Passwords should match");
            }
        });
```

Finally it could look like this:

```
public class ResetPasswordForUpdateDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<ResetPasswordForUpdateDto>
{
    public ResetPasswordForUpdateDtoValidator()
    {
        CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

        RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please enter the password");
        RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please enter the confirmation password");

        RuleFor(x => x).Custom((x, context) =>
        {
            if (x.Password != x.ConfirmPassword)
            {
                context.AddFailure(nameof(x.Password), "Passwords should match");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind some validators only work on the serverside such as 'When' and 'Must'

To properly display the error message on the client you can simply do this:

`RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword).NotEmpty().Equal(x => x.Password);`

The following are supported on the client (from the [docs](https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet#clientside-validation)):

- NotNull/NotEmpty
- Matches (regex)
- InclusiveBetween (range)
- CreditCard
- Email
- EqualTo (cross-property equality comparison)
- MaxLength
- MinLength
- Length

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand what do you need, but:

If you **need to allow empty password**, use [`[Required]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) as well as `[Compare]`.
If you **don't**, leave only `[Compare]` attribute.

Comment: Password is optional, and not is Required. The problem is, when password is null and confirm passowrd id null, then display ErrorMassage: "Password and ConfirmPassword are not the same".

Comment: I think you wrote opposite of what you are thinking. "If you need to allow empty password, use only [Compare] attribute."

Answer (score 0):

If password is optional then only use [Compare] attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Password and confirm password validation

try thisone:

```
           <script>
function checkPass()
{
    var Password = document.getElementById('Password');
    var Confirm_Password = document.getElementById('Confirm_Password');
   var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
    var goodColor = "#66cc66";
    var badColor = "#ff6666";
    if(Password.value == Confirm_Password.value){
       Confirm_Password.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
        message.style.color = goodColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!"
    }else{
       Confirm_Password.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
        message.style.color = badColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Do Not Match!"
    }
} 
</script>


<div> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/code_examples/tutorial.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/code_examples/passtest.js"></script>
 <div class="tutorialWrapper"></div>


<tr>   <td>  Password : </td> <td>   <div class="fieldWrapper">

            <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password">
        </div> </td>  </tr>   

                 <tr>   <td>  

                        Confirm Password : </td> <td> 
        <div class="fieldWrapper">

            <input type="password" name="Confirm_Password" id="Confirm_Password" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;">
            <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span></td></tr>
```